# How to demonstrate LaTeX formula with Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have attempted to demonstrate a LaTeX formula with Gnuplot 5.0.
But I found that some LaTeX commands are unavailable.

This is my Gnuplot Code:

```
set termoption enhanced

set title   "Title test^a \alpha $\alpha$" font "CMU-Serif, 18"
set xlabel  "Month"
set ylabel  "Precipitation (mm)"
set xrange  [0.5: 12.5]
set xtics   1,1,12
set key
set pointintervalbox 2

plot    "08_Data.dat"   using 1:2 with linespoints \
                        linecolor "#FF7800" linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 0.75 pointinterval -1 \
                        title "Beijing",\
        "08_Data.dat"   using 1:3 with linespoints \
                        linecolor "#00A0DC" linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 0.75 pointinterval -1 \
                        title "Shanghai",

set output
pause (-1)
```

As a result, the LaTeX command `test^a` works well but the LaTeX `\alpha` and `$\alpha$` don't work:

[image]

This is the file: 08_Data.dat :

```
1       2.5     38.1
2       5.1     58.4
3       10.2    81.3    
4       25.4    101.6
5       27.9    114.3
6       71.1    152.4
7       175.3   129.5
8       182.9   132.1
9       48.3    154.9
10      17.8    61.0
11      5.1     50.8
12      2.5     35.6
```

Comment: what editor are you using?

Comment: @forecaster vs code.

Answer (score 3):

```
   set term tikz standalone size 7cm, 3cm fontscale 0.6
   set ylabel '{\LaTeX\ -- $ \gamma $}'
   set xlabel '{\LaTeX\ -- $ x $}'
   set output 'example.tex'
   plot [0:1] gamma(x) title '$ \gamma(x) $'
   unset output
   !pdflatex example
```

[image: screenshot of pdf output]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to directly type in the alpha character in the gnuplot code? I guess gnuplot understands UTF-8.

```
set title "test^a α α" font "CMU-Serif, 18"
plot x
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: sorry, then I misunderstood your question. Have you checked `help terminal latex`?

Comment: The gnuplot "enhanced text" mode is an alternative to LaTeX, not a layer on top of it.  If you want TeX type-setting then use one of the tex or latex based gnuplot terminals rather than one of the enhanced text terminals.  I suggest `set term tikz`

Comment: `set term epslatex` works as well, you can easily convert the output to pdf after that

Comment: @Ethan @Vladimir Thank you very much! I have learned how to covert .plt to .tex with ```set term epslatex standalone``` and ```set output "test.tex```. but I think this method is very cumbersome and inefficient. How to generate the pdf file directly with LaTeX formula.